# Working with WDS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wds, waik

I work with WDS on Windows Server 2008-R2. I need to create some WIM images. For creating images i need  the ImageX utility it is member of WAIK. Can i download the ImageX  separately from the WAIK? Also i need articles to create images with ImageX  (both of them boot and system images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download the WAIK here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=696dd665-9f76-4177-a811-39c26d3b3b34&displaylang=en) and then instructions can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=901663E1-934F-4793-8EAE-7C0A1CCB83A5&displaylang=en). Both are free downloads and should get you started. The only way to get imagex is from the WAIK toolkit.